# como puedo agregar parametro a una url con jquery

Tags: jquery

Hay alguna forma agregar un parametro a un a url 
me encotre con este script pero aun no logre entenderlo

HTML

```
<select class="form-control js-sort-by" name="sort_by">
<option value="price-ascending">Precio: Menor a Mayor</option>
<option value="price-descending">Precio: Mayor a Menor</option>
<option value="alpha-ascending">A - Z</option>
<option value="alpha-descending">Z - A</option>
<option value="created-descending">Más Nuevo al más Viejo</option>
<option value="created-ascending">Más Viejo al más Nuevo</option>
<option value="best-selling" selected="">Más Vendidos</option>
<input type="submit" value="">
</select>

<script>
$('.js-sort-by').change(function(){
var params = LS.urlParams;
params['sort_by'] = $(this).val();
var sort_params_array = [];
for (var key in params) {
if ($.inArray(key, ['results_only', 'page']) == -1) {
sort_params_array.push(key + '=' + params[key]);
}
}
var sort_params = sort_params_array.join('&');
window.location = window.location.pathname + '?' + sort_params;
});
 </script>
```

la idea mia seria al cambiar de opcion que se agrege el parametro 
sort_by

midominio.com/categor/?sort_by=created-ascending

Comment: deseas agragrar un parametro al valor del atribu url?, www.midominio.com+parametro?

Comment: claro si seria un midominio.com/index?param=valor

Comment: agrega mas informacion. tu html tambien

Comment: dale perfecto ;)

Answer (score 1):

Proba de la siguiente forma (copialo y ejecutalo en tu pc, el snippet de aca no lo arma bien)

```html
<select class="form-control js-sort-by" name="sort_by">
  <option value="price-ascending">Precio: Menor a Mayor</option>
  <option value="price-descending">Precio: Mayor a Menor</option>
  <option value="alpha-ascending">A - Z</option>
  <option value="alpha-descending">Z - A</option>
  <option value="created-descending">Más Nuevo al más Viejo</option>
  <option value="created-ascending">Más Viejo al más Nuevo</option>
  <option value="best-selling" selected="">Más Vendidos</option>
</select>

<label> Probar varios cambios en el select para ver la url</label>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $('.js-sort-by').on('change', function() {
  var valor = $(this).val();
  var direccion = window.location.pathname + '?sort_by=' + valor;
  alert("DIRECCION A LA QUE VOY A SER REDIRECCIONADO " + direccion)
  

  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?sort_by=' + valor
  });


  $.get = function(key)   { 
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[');  
    key = key.replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');  
    var pattern = "[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)";  
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern);  
    var url = unescape(window.location.href);  
    var results = regex.exec(url);  
    if (results === null) {  
        return null;  
    } else {  
        return results[1];  
    }  
  }
 
    var a = $.get("sort_by");

    if (a != null) {
      alert("VARIABLE QUE ESTA LLEGANDO AL SORT BY: " + a)
}

 </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Agregale a tu select el atributo id, en este caso fue `id="sortBy"`

```
<select class="form-control js-sort-by" name="sort_by" id="sortBy">
<option value="price-ascending">Precio: Menor a Mayor</option>
<option value="price-descending">Precio: Mayor a Menor</option>
<option value="alpha-ascending">A - Z</option>
<option value="alpha-descending">Z - A</option>
<option value="created-descending">Más Nuevo al más Viejo</option>
<option value="created-ascending">Más Viejo al más Nuevo</option>
<option value="best-selling" selected="">Más Vendidos</option>
<input type="submit" value="">
</select>
```

en tu js, con una funcion de change de jquery solo tomas el valor de tu select.

```
    <script>

        $("#sortBy").change(function(){

             // tomas el valor de tu select.
            var dispatch_value = $("#dispatch").val();

            // lo guardas en una variable que deseas
            var menu = dispatch_value + "?Param="+dispatch_value;

 // con la funcion de jquery attr le mandas el valor de tu url guardado en la variable menu, este simplemente lo sobreescribe cada vez que se encuentre un cambio.
                $('#call_dispatch').attr('href',menu);


          // aqui simpemente lo pruebas
                var x = $('#call_dispatch').attr('href');


          alert(window.location.pathname + x);
// window.location =  window.location.pathname + x
        });
    </script>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.